# How to set target on url action in PDFLib, php function PDF_create_action

Tags: php, pdflib

I've added URL's to a PDF created with PHP's built in functions.  I have not been able to figure out how to have the links open in a new window, ie target="_new".  I've been looking for the available options for PDF_create_action and PDF_create_annotation but have not found much written on either.  Following is the code I use:

```
$url = PDF_create_action($p, "URI", "url {" . $myUrl . "}");
PDF_create_annotation ($p, $x, $x, ($x + 50), ($x + 10), "Link", "linewidth=0 action {activate $url}");
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I don't think PDFs have the notion of `target="_blank"`, after all, they are not generated via HTML (even if your PDF library supports that).

Also, PDFs aren't always viewed in a browser, so having them open in a new window is semantically meaningless if the PDF viewer must load the user's browser anyway.

Comment: That is a good point.  I suppose it may be good enough to force a download of the PDF file instead of allowing it to open in the browser.  This way, as they click links in the file, they can view them in the browser and still have their PDF file open.

Comment: @dt1021 That may be a viable option :)